Minimum Row Count condition based on values of all columns in pandas DataFrame
Suppose I have three columns in a pandas DataFrame without any null or empty values.

Facility always has unique values per item.
An item can have one or more vendors associated with it.
The same vendor can show up more than once for different facilities for a given item.
A facility is never associated with more than one vendor for a given item.
Item values are ordered.
Every row is unique.

Example of the data:



Column Vendor
Column Item
Column Facility




V1
I1
F1


V1
I1
F2


V2
I1
F4


V1
I2
F1


V1
I2
F2


V2
I2
F3


V3
I2
F5


V3
I2
F6


V3
I3
F3


V1
I4
F2


V4
I4
F4


V4
I4
F5


V1
I5
F1


V1
I5
F4



How do I create a DataFrame that contains the following?: "For every item, if there is more than one vendor associated with that item, give me all rows for that item (otherwise exclude all rows associated with that item)."
In this example, I would want a DataFrame of all rows for I1, I2, and I4 because they have more than 1 unique vendor associated with them, and I would exclude all rows involving I3 and I5 as there is only one vendor associated with them.
I tried to create a list of unique vendors for each item loop with a conditional of len(Appended_Vendor_List_var) > 1, but so far no luck.

Hi John and welcome on SO. Do you mind to add your expected output?

You can use a groupby.transform('nunique') and boolean indexing:
out = df[df.groupby('Column Item')['Column Vendor'].transform('nunique').gt(1)]

Output:
   Column Vendor Column Item Column Facility
0             V1          I1              F1
1             V1          I1              F2
2             V2          I1              F4
3             V1          I2              F1
4             V1          I2              F2
5             V2          I2              F3
6             V3          I2              F5
7             V3          I2              F6
9             V1          I4              F2
10            V4          I4              F4
11            V4          I4              F5

Intermediate:
   Column Vendor Column Item Column Facility  nunique  nunique>1
0             V1          I1              F1        2       True
1             V1          I1              F2        2       True
2             V2          I1              F4        2       True
3             V1          I2              F1        3       True
4             V1          I2              F2        3       True
5             V2          I2              F3        3       True
6             V3          I2              F5        3       True
7             V3          I2              F6        3       True
8             V3          I3              F3        1      False
9             V1          I4              F2        2       True
10            V4          I4              F4        2       True
11            V4          I4              F5        2       True
12            V1          I5              F1        1      False
13            V1          I5              F4        1      False

Variant using drop_duplicates and isin:
drop = (df.drop_duplicates(['Column Vendor', 'Column Item'])['Column Item']
          .drop_duplicates(keep=False)
       )

out = df[~df['Column Item'].isin(drop)]


This works, thank you!

import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Vendor': ['V1', 'V1', 'V2', 'V1', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V3', 'V3', 'V1', 'V4', 'V4', 'V1', 'V1'],
    'Item': ['I1', 'I1', 'I1', 'I2', 'I2', 'I2', 'I2', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4', 'I4', 'I4', 'I5', 'I5'],
    'Facility': ['F1', 'F2', 'F4', 'F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F5', 'F6', 'F3', 'F2', 'F4', 'F5', 'F1', 'F4']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_filtered = df[df.groupby('Item')['Vendor'].transform('nunique') > 1]
print(df_filtered )
"""
   Vendor Item Facility
0      V1   I1       F1
1      V1   I1       F2
2      V2   I1       F4
3      V1   I2       F1
4      V1   I2       F2
5      V2   I2       F3
6      V3   I2       F5
7      V3   I2       F6
9      V1   I4       F2
10     V4   I4       F4
11     V4   I4       F5
"""

